# Не заменяется компонент input checkout form`ы magento 2

Tags: magento

пытаюсь изменить поле input с name="street" для теста, на обычный параграф. Для этого: 
1) в папке Checkout/view/frontend/web/template создаю файл custom-checkout-form.html и записываю в него 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]


2) далее в папке Checkout/view/frontend/web/layout я создал файл checkout_index_index.xml, в который записал

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Remove fields-->
                                                            <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VpLab_Checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Чтобы проверить точно ли он берет шаблон отсюда отключал input, все работало, с переопределением - нет, заранее спасибо!
Вот, что выводи в консоль, когда я прописываю

```
require('uiRegistry').get('index = street')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для замены шаблона надо изменять не `component` свойство, а `template`:

```
...
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">VpLab_Checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
    ...
```

В этом случае компонент потянет ваш шаблон, при условии что он существует по указанному пути.

**PS:** судя по описанию вам вообще необходимо заменить `elementTmpl`, т.к. именно это свойство отвечает за вывод непосредственно инпута, `template` же просто обертка которая его отрисовывает.

Comment: Хорошо, по логике вещей он же может заменить стандартный инпут на все то, что я напишу в шаблоне , так?

Comment: Да, к сожалению оба name не работают... В каком направлении искать проблему, есть какие-нибудь варианты? А вообще суть задачи в том, что нужно разбить один инпут с name "street" на улицу, дом, квартиу/офис, в таком духе

Comment: @ЯнСоколиков Заменить может на все что угодно, но не факт что это будет сходу работать. Проверить можно запросив ваш компонент используя `require('uiRegistry').get('index = street')` в консоли браузера и посмотрев его конфигурацию. Какая у вас версия Мадженто?

Comment: Прописав данную команду он вывел сам этот объект. Версия Мадженто 2.1.7

Comment: @ЯнСоколиков отлично, в свойствах объекта есть `template`, `elementTmpl`, `component` и т.д. Смотрите какие они имеют значения. Если не те что вы указывали, значит проблема в кеше\разметке(xml). Если те что вы указали, но отображается по старому - проверяйте ваши файлы шаблонов.

Comment: Прикрепил фотографию при выводе этого объекта, там есть атрибут name, не он ли случаем должен использоваться при формировании xml дерева, типа checkout->children->steps->children->billing-step и т.д?

Comment: @ЯнСоколиков У вас в примере (в впоросе) shipping-step , на нем и нужно проверять. billing-step это уже второй шаг чекаута. Дерево формируется по index